# App crashes and no report dialog

Tags: android, service, crash

My app is available on the Play Store and one of my users reported that it crashes on his phone but he is not able to send me the logs since there is no report dialog.
What could be the source of this issue and how to fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you send another build with crashlytics and criticism in place and try to replicate the crash. Also go to your dashboard of play store and check for crash logs.

Comment: where is crashlytics mentioned ?

Comment: Add it in the next build, and ask him to replicate

Comment: If you trust that tool go ahead, use it